# "He is none but fit for the job" - does this sentence convey the same meaning as the following sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, transformation

I'm learning sentence transformation. Though my main confusion with the meaning of the 3rd sentence, could anybody please check the following 3 sentences and let me know whether they convey the same meaning or not.

***1.** He is the only person fit for the job.

**2.** No other person but he is fit for the job.

**3.** He is none but fit for the job.*

Comment: (1) is idiomatic English, (2) means the same but doesn't sound very natural, (3) is meaningless.

Comment: @KateBunting Just one point, isn't (3) sounds like 'He is not fit for anything but a particular job.'? Or doesn't (3) convey any meaning at all?

Comment: I have already said that it is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The first two sentences are clear in there meaning.  The first is simple correct.  The second uses a "textbook" style, with grammar copied from Latin.

The third is hypercorrect and fails to make sense. I suppose it literally means "all his characteristics make him fit for the job", and probably intended to mean "He would be very good at this job".  But its odd, because taken at face value it would seem to suggest irrelevant characteristics like "hair colour" also make him fit for the job, which is odd. Or it could mean "he is fit for only this job" (and so can't do anything else) which is a critisim.

The first two mean "nobody else is fit for the job". The third (if it means anything) doesn't mean that.

Sentence transformation isn't really a thing.  There might be different ways of expressing the same idea in English, but you don't mechanically take a sentence and learn the transformations of it.